# Unable to set custom class for UICollectionView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm unable to set the custom class attribute in Storyboard mode for a UICollectionView. Below you can see the screenshot of where I'm entering this. Generally when I extend a view controller it will autocomplete the custom class name, but in this case it doesn't, and if I click away to a different UI element and click back to the CollectionView then the custom class is empty again (shows the UICollectionView placeholder).

[image: Custom Class attribute]

Here is the MyMediaCollectionController.m

```
#import "MyMediaCollectionController.h"
@interface MyMediaCollectionController ()
@end

@implementation MyMediaCollectionController
    static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
@end
```

and MyMediaCollectionController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyMediaCollectionController : UICollectionViewController
@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Close and reopen your xcode.

Comment: I tried this, no luck.

Comment: UICollectionViewController vs UICollectionView? View vs ViewController?

Comment: If you have created view of UIViewController and then added UICollectionView than you need to create subclass of UIViewController and add delegate of UICollectionViewDelegate.

Comment: Yes Sujay, I have a UIViewController that contains the UICollectionView.

Comment: @StevenBennett, that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code and screenshot it seems that you subclassed the wrong base class. You need to use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) instead of [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/)

Change:

```
@interface MyMediaCollectionController : UICollectionViewController
@end
```

to:

```
@interface MyMediaCollectionController : UICollectionView
@end
```

When you do this you need to change your implementation also, change it like:

```
@implementation MyMediaCollectionController
static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}
@end
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I can now set the custom class in the Storyboard. One question, how can I reference the collectionView from within awakeFromNib? Before I could use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.collectionView reloadData];});` but now I get the error that the collectionView property wasn't found.

Comment: Looks like I can reference it with just `self` now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Your class must be subclass of `UIViewController`

MyMediaCollectionController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyMediaCollectionController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate>
@end
```

Comment: When I use this, I get the an error `Property 'collectionView' not found on object of type 'MyMediaCollectionController *` on this line `[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];`. Any idea on how I can access the collectionView from inside the subclass?

Comment: Yes I changed it in MyMediaCollectionController.h

Comment: @StevenBennett, don't try manually. better you can add new subclass of `UIViewcontroller` and later add delegate of `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource`

Comment: and than add all the required delegate methods of `UICollectionView` in `MyMediaCollectionController`.

Comment: Can't I subclass the UICollectionViewController independently without delegating through the UIViewController?

Comment: @StevenBennett, Yes you can. but the as per your view design that **you have added `UICollectionView` inside `UIView`** that is why I have suggested to add new subclass of `UIViewcontroller` and later add delegate of `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource`.